# Extract the max values for row and column

Tags: r

I need to fin the values for which the row max and the column max are for the same position. Test data (The real data doesn't need to be a square matrix):

```
scores<-structure(c(0.4, 0.6, 0.222222222222222, 0.4, 0.4, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 
0.285714285714286), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", 
"b", "c"), c("d", "e", "f")))
```

I already found which are the columns/rows with the max value for that row/column.

```
rows<-structure(list(a = c("d", "e"), b = "d", c = "f"), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c"))
cols<-structure(list(d = "b", e = c("a", "b"), f = "b"), .Names = c("d", 
"e", "f"))
```

But I don't manage to get the values from the matrix. The problem are when the same (max) value appear twice or more. I don't know how to check the indices of that case. I tried using mapply:

```
mapply(function(x, y) {
    cols[x] == rows[y] 
    }, rows, cols)
```

But this stops when rows or cols has more than one element.

Expected output: `c(0.6, 0.4)`
The first is the max value of column 1 and row 2, the second value is the max value of row 1 and column 2.

```
            d   e         f   | Max
a   0.4000000 0.4 0.2500000   0.4
b   0.6000000 0.4 0.5000000   0.6
c   0.2222222 0.0 0.2857143   0.2857
Max:  0.6     0.4 0.5
```

As you can see for row 2 and column 1 the max value is the same, and for row 1 and column 1 it is the same value, but for row 3 and column 3 it isn't

Comment: In your `mapply` function where is the `scores` data?

Comment: It isn't, it is an attempt to retrieve the indices somehow.

Comment: What about `Map(function(x, y) max(scores[x, y]), cols, rows)`

Comment: It doesn't output the expected output, but it might be a way to go

Comment: So, if there are unequal lengths, what do you want to do.  Also based on the way you showed `Map(function(x, y) unlist(cols[x]) == unlist(rows[y]) , rows, cols)` none of them are TRUE

Comment: I have added a "graphical" visualization of the problem, I want to implement equation 3 of this [article](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/23/13/i529/231121/Information-theory-applied-to-the-sparse-gene) See figure 2 for a clearer? visualization of the problem. In case of unequal lengths, it doesn't really matter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144918/discussion-between-llopis-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think , I understood what you are trying to do. Not an optimal solution though.

We find out the indices for maximum value in rows as well as column and then find out the indices which `intersect` and display the corresponding value from the dataframe.

```
a1 <- which(apply(scores, 1, function(x) x == max(x)))
a2 <- which(apply(scores, 2, function(x) x == max(x)))
scores[intersect(a1, a2)]

#[1] 0.6 0.4
```

And in one-line

```
scores[intersect(which(apply(scores, 1, function(x) x == max(x))), 
                 which(apply(scores, 2, function(x) x == max(x))))]
```

Comment: Although, this gives an answer for the current example, let me know if I have left out some corner cases. Also, I believe there should be some better way for the same approach, couldn't think of any right now.

Comment: Clever! Many thanks, I don't think it left corner cases, but I will check with tests

Comment: I just want to note for future readers that apply fills the matrix by column which in the first case results in wrong indices unless you use `which(t(apply(....`

Comment: @Llopis I don't think that would matter because we are using `apply` for both rows and columns. So if we are transposing it with `t` we need to do it for both of them or none of them as shown in the above example.

Comment: If you change the scores[1, 1] to 0.5 and output the apply(scores, 1, function(x) x == max(x)), you will see that it matters to select the right index. But, I am unsure if it is needed in both of them ;\

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want:

```
# Compute rows and columns max and rows max positions
row_max<-apply(scores, 1, max)
row_max_pos<-apply(scores, 1, which.max)
col_max<-apply(scores, 2, max)

# For each row, check if max is equal to corresponding column max
res <- sapply(1:length(row_max), 
              function(i) ifelse(row_max[i] == col_max[row_max_pos[i]], T, F))
row_max[res]
```

It also work with same max values on multiple rows/columns, for example with this data:

```
scores <- structure(c(0.4, 0.6, 0.222222222222222, 0.4, 0.4, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 
                      0.285714285714286, 0.13, 0.2, 0.6), .Dim = c(4L, 3L), 
                      .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), c("e", "f", "g")))
```

Comment: This return the expected outcome however it doesn't take into account where the max value is obtained. Thanks anyway

Comment: What kind of position do you mean?

Comment: No, but the position is relevant to decide if I need to store it or not. If I replace the scores[1,1]  by 0.5 the output would be 0.6 and 0.5, but the max of 0.5 in the row and in the columns would be in different places

Comment: You were right, I've just updated my answer and tested it with other data, it works correctly now.